# Why does $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}-1}}{1-e^{-1}})^n = e^z$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital, probability-limit-theorems

As part of a probability calculation (convergence of a sequence of CDF's)I need to calculate $$  \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}-1}}{1-e^{-1}})^n$$ Wolframalpha says that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}-1}}{1-e^{-1}})^n = e^z.$$ I can't figure out why... can you?

Comment: simplify the given term at first

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't go anywhere... Can you give me a hint?

Comment: For the person who downvoted: May I ask why?

Comment: In this forum there are  death eaters. I think  one of them did it.

Comment: I thought so...

Comment: With the series expansion one gets $\,...=\displaystyle (1+\frac{z}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2}))^n  \approx (1+\frac{z}{n})^n \to e^z\,$ .

Comment: "For the person who downvoted: May I ask why?" For the total lack of personal input perhaps, who knows?

Comment: unnecessary. You could have posted a comment requiring my work so far. Or just left it be. I did think about the problem for quite some time. And seeing how intricate the solution is, it's not that I missed something obvious. Also, nasty, pseudoironic snark is how people get into stupid twitter/youtube fights... unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: @ghthorpe Necessary and useful is to use @, especially when explicitely taking to task the content of a previous comment. Re the "arguments" in your comment (that is, the constructive part), how comes that you had **nothing** to propose as personal input if you "did think about the problem for quite some time"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}-1}}{1-e^{-1}}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}-1}}{1-e^{-1}}-1\right)^n=$$ 
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}}}{e-1}\right)^{\frac{e-1}{1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}}}\cdot\frac{n\left(1-e^{\frac{-z(e-1)}{n}}\right)}{e-1}}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-e^{-z(e-1)x}}{(e-1)x}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-z(e-1)x}-1}{-z(e-1)x}\cdot z}=e^z$$